# How can I do a truly verbatim search on Google

Tags: google-search

In order to find a solution to a certain problem I'm having, I'm trying to do a Google search with the terms:

```
copy "msgstore.db" to new phone
```

A bit of context must be provided before I can continue:

- `msgstore.db` is a file which contains the Whatsapp messages in **unencrypted** form. It does not exist outside the Whatsapp DATA folder within the Android system (so it cannot be accessed by conventional means). It`s the working database file for Whatsapp.
- Anything ending in `.crypt` is an encrypted database file, created for backup purposes in the sdcard. Thus it can be accessed by anyone.

Now, the vast majority of websites out there are full or articles directed to "casual" users, so they only contain info pertaining to the second case, but these are useless to me since I'm trying to do something very peculiar. ([Posted on Android.SE](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/150071/57668)).

I need results containing the exact words "msgstore.db", but my query is returning pages containing keywords like `msgstore.db.crypt` or `msgstore-YYYY-MM-DD.db.crypt8` despite the fact that I isolated the terms with quotation marks.

Is my query wrong, and if so, what would be the right way to do such a search?

Comment: Your query is telling Google just to include the search terms you specified, NOT to *not* include pages containing other keywords. So your results *do* contain the exact words `msgstore.db` but they *also* contain other things because you haven't specifically excluded them. Aren't you potentially missing important results by excluding anything that *doesn't* contain the literal `msgstore.db`? Just because it includes `msgstore.db.crypt` doesn't mean the result is less valid, eg, maybe the best answer also contains `msgstore.db.crypt` as the person is describing something that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try to negate the terms you don't want. Wildcards may help.

Try something like this:

```
copy "msgstore.db" to new phone -"msgstore.db.crypt" -"msgstore-*.db.crypt8"
```

Comment: Good idea. Although it's not working for me. The results are much the same as previously. Did you test it, and did it work?